# How to give padding bottom for overflow hidden div?

Tags: html, css, button, overflow

Contents are coming dynamically from databaes,at the `bottom of div` i have a `see more button` ,clicking on button the div will expand up to 400px;

```
#content
  {

    width:180px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
}
  #bt
  {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
   }
```

**html**

```
<div id="content">
<p>content content ....</p>
<input type="button" value="see more" id="bt">
</div>
```

But how to give padding bottom to this div? Is there any other css trick to do padding bottom for `overflow :hidden div`

Answer (score 0):

Try This. This might help you

```
#bt
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: Please add a padding-bottom:50px to the #content.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a `padding-bottom:50px` to the #content.